# Group Messaging and Group mailing using HTML5

Tags: html, hybrid-mobile-app

Do we have any possibility to implement group messaging and group mailing system using HTML5 for my cross platform Mobile app.

Comment: "_Do we have any possibility_" Sure you do. Computers are amazing and can do amazing things. Now, what exactly is the **specific** problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using HTML5's Server Sent Events for group messaging. There is a noticable lag, but it works!

As for mailing, you can simulate group email with a messaging system that allows multiple recipients. Using PHP/Javascript you could implement a nice WYSIWYG Editor.

Simply using PHP mail function may be risky due to possible overuse or misuse and server/host limitations, so an online email service (such as PostMark for example) exists at a low enough cost to handle things with more certainty.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp
And: https://postmarkapp.com/